# partial rendering update panel on modal popup extender close

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

In my form I have a `listview` and a `panel` which is used as popup window inside a `updatepanel`.

I am dynamically creating popup window using `modalpopupextender` on `listview` `ltemcommand`.

here is my code to open the popup

```
protected void LstCreativeBin_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "UploadFile":
                ListViewDataItem currentItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
                DataKey currentDataKey = LstCreativeBin.DataKeys[currentItem.DisplayIndex];
                int contestid = Convert.ToInt32(currentDataKey["participantSlno"]);
                IframeEdit.Attributes.Add("src", "Uploadfile.aspx?id=" + Convert.ToString(contestid));
                ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

My problem is the page is refreshing even if it's inside the `updatepanel`. I have added the `LstCreativeBin_ItemCommand` to asynchronous trigger in update.

What is need here is :

1. Opening the pop up asynchronously.
2. Refreshing the update panel on popup close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about opening the modalpopupextender without going to code-behind ... if you open it with dynamic controls, you can point the modalpopupextender to TargetControlID a dummy like a hidden control, and you can add to each listview item a onclick to hidden_control.click() or just $find(modal).show()